# First Non Value in a filtered table

Tags: powerbi, dax

_Hi, I struggle to return the first non blank value of my "BDD Index" Table filtered with 'BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine] = [Mesure 2 MAX ordrerLine].

I Don't understand why the following code returns an empty table, whereas when I replace [Mesure 2 MAX orderLine] by a number & SELECTEDVALUE('BDD Index'[Bat]) by "IGH", it works ? :

```
FILTER(
            'BDD Index',
            'BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine] = [Mesure 2 MAX orderLine] && 'BDD Index'[Bat] = SELECTEDVALUE('BDD Index'[Bat])
        )
```

And then my DAX formula won't work :

```
Mesure FNBV = 
    FIRSTNONBLANKVALUE(
        'BDD Index'[Date & Heure],
        FILTER(
            'BDD Index',
            'BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine] = [Mesure 2 MAX orderLine] && 'BDD Index'[Bat] = SELECTEDVALUE('BDD Index'[Bat])
        )
    )
```

Besides, When I calculate the following measure with an IF evaluation, it breaks my filter context and i can't understand why, even when I add a KEEPFILTER context :

```
Mesure TEST_ =  IF(
    HASONEVALUE('BDD Index'[Bat]) && SELECTEDVALUE('BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine]) = [Mesure 2 MAX orderLine],
    1,
    0 )
```

[Here is the link of my file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!An2aQoxg76Kv8WguMBnpf1fG8NNM?e=zHmrVk)

Thanks in advance !

Image of filter context broken
[image]

instead of (without IF measure)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Mesure 2 MAX orderLine` measure to:

```
Mesure 2 MAX orderLine = 
  CALCULATE(
    MAX('BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine]),
    ALLSELECTED('BDD Index')
  )
```

And update `Mesure FNBV` to:

```
Mesure FNBV = 
  var maxOrder = [Mesure 2 MAX orderLine]
  return CALCULATE(
    FIRSTNONBLANK('BDD Index'[Date & Heure], 1),
    'BDD Index'[Ordre TimeLine] = maxOrder
  )
```

See if that is what you are after. If it is then I'll follow-up with an explanation or answer any questions. It wasn't clear what you were intending to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Works perfectly for the FNBV measure with the var ! For the First measure, using allselected breaks the context filter of my table and adds the result of the measure to all the Date-Time datas of my other building. Using keepfilter avoids that. BUT, when I add my IF measure, it breaks it again : How could I do it ?

Comment: What do you want `MAX orderLine` to do? Which column is building? Can you give an overview of the table and what you need?

Comment: Max orderline is ok. Mesure FNBV is ok. When i calculate the mesure_Test, I need to focus on the date related to max Orderline. It works BUT it breaks my filter context. I try to put an image above.

Comment: All the lines with blank in the "mesure 2 MAX OrderLine" column are irrelevant and related to a building not filtered...

Comment: Oh, just don't return 0.if a measure returns any value then it will show for that row. So just return 1 or BLANK()

Comment: Arhhhhhh. how dumb am I ! Many thanks ! Subject solved then ! Have a nice end of day.